# Why is sqlite auto_increment not incrementing?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've got a database set up to store notes. I want to auto increment the first column. I've tried this, but when I read from the database every result in that column is 'null'.
This is the code for creating the DB.

```
private static final String NOTES_TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + NOTES_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                COLUMN_NAMES[0] + " INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_NAMES[1] + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_NAMES[2] + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_NAMES[3] + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_NAMES[4] + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_NAMES[5] + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_NAMES[6] + " TEXT);";
```

This is the code for getting the DB result.

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor result = db.query(NOTES_TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAMES, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    result.moveToFirst();
    result.moveToNext();

    System.out.println(result.getInt(0));
    System.out.println(result.getString(1));
```

This is the output from logcat

```
04-09 17:56:17.981 22147-22147/com.example.a8460p.locationotes I/System.out: 0
04-09 17:56:17.981 22147-22147/com.example.a8460p.locationotes I/System.out: notetitle1234567890
```

Comment: Does the table actually contain any data?

Comment: yes, the second System.out.println outputs notetitle1234567890. I am also able to add data and populate a list with the data. It's just the auto_increment column that doesnt seem to be recording anything

Comment: Because you are not applying it to `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column.

Comment: @PetSerAl `INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT` (without `PRIMARY KEY`) would drop a syntax error. That this parses silently is because of the typo `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Sqlite silently ignores unsupported column constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` (as opposed to [`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)) is not supported in sqlite.

This is a little non-obvious, because sqlite silently ignores column constraints it does not recognize:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test (
    a INTEGER FABBELBABBEL NOT NULL
);
sqlite> .schema test
CREATE TABLE test (a INTEGER FABBELBABBEL NOT NULL);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test (a) VALUES (1);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test (a) VALUES (NULL);
Error: NOT NULL constraint failed: test.a
```

`AUTOINCREMENT` on the other hand, is supported for integer primary keys and only there, so the obvious workaround attempt is not supported, either:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test (a INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, b INTEGER);
Error: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error
```

In short: Auto increment is only available for integer primary keys.